# Joomla: Is there a module render plugin event?

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla1.5

Due to some caching issues, I need to explicitly bypass the cache, for a specific module, if certain URL parameters are present. The workaround I've arrived at is to hack the `render()` function in `libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/module.php`, along the lines of:

```
function render( $module, $params = array(), $content = null )
{
    // Existing code:
    $mod_params = new JParameter( $module->params );

    // My hack:
    if ($module->module == 'mod_foo')
    {
        if (certain URL parameters are present)
        {
            $mod_params->set('cache', 0);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Of course, hacking the core joomla code is a terrible idea, one which I'd like to avoid if at all possible. So, is there an appropriate hook I can plugin to in order to achieve the same? I don't think I can do anything at the module level, since it won't even be inspected if the renderer has already decided to fetch it from cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first question no there isn't a module render event, here's [the plugin doc's and the list of events in Joomla!](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin)

Turn off caching for your module.

See this article on [The Art Of Joomla](http://www.theartofjoomla.com/joomla-caching-explained.html), additional articles you could look at:

1. [Using Cache to Speed Up your code](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_caching_to_speed_up_your_code)
2. [JCache API](http://docs.joomla.org/JCache)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not currently an option. Turning off caching for the module kills the site under heavy load. This is hardly surprising since the current configuration uses a *huge* number of DB queries: ~ 300 for the home page. Turning on caching, of course, reduces this (although still nowhere near what is reasonable ...) and just about lets the site breathe under strain.

Comment: Turning off cache for just your module kills the site?

Comment: *The* module, please, not *my* module ;-) Yes, the site can only handle a certain amount of traffic (just like *any* site) and ~ 300 DB queries vs ~ 150 queries (or whatever the exact difference is - it's big, certainly) makes enough of a difference to handle the current traffic. Of course, as traffic increases, I'll either need to keep optimising the site/code (looks like there's a LONG way to go ...) or throw more hardware at it. Caching some of the worst-offending modules is the first step in this process.

Comment: P.S. it's worth mentioning that the SEF module that performs a database lookup for every link on the page doesn't help. The module that I'm caching outputs ~ 100 links.

Comment: Ahh.. my bad - there isn't a module render event (updated my answer). Maybe the module's DB access can be improved?

Comment: Oh, that's certainly the correct answer, it's just a LOT more work than caching the module. But I'm a firm believer that caching should be an absolute last resort; too bad many third-party joomla developers seem to take caching for granted :-(